# Facebook like box is suddenly right-aligned

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I manage/webmaster half a dozen websites that have facebook like boxes on their index pages. These were all working fine until yesterday, when suddenly they all began to display to the right of the page (where previously they had been centered). No changes have been made to any of these pages in the last day or two, so I can't think of any reason why they would all suddenly right-align.
Some of these scripts are between "center" tags, Others are inside centered tables. But they're still displaying to the right of the page. I've tried everything I can think of to get them to display in the middle of the page again, but nothing I've tried works. I'm also curious to know why they would all suddenly lose their center alignment.
Anyone have any ideas?
Any help would be very much appreciated.

You can see an example of what I'm talking about at holisticspain-dot-net

Answer (score 1):

We already apply some styling to our button (it is surrounded in `<li>` tags, but we found we had to change the style for this.

We previously had this style applied

```
.fb-tool {position:relative;left:8px;}
```

We changed it to this.

```
.fb-tool {position:relative;left:8px; text-align:left;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.fb-like-box.fb_iframe_widget *
{
    text-align: left !important;
}
```

This worked as a temporary fix as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just a short answer - might help perhaps. I changed the `display` property of `.fb_iframe_widget` to relative with !important and it fixed the sudden leftiness.

Answer (score 0):

Following Harold Neal and Sergei S's suggestions, you can add text-align:left; to the default style="background-color:#000000;" portion of the  tag.